# import error: No module named trajoptpy

Tags: python

'em running a python code, but in python code 'em facing problem with these lines of code

```
import trajoptpy
import trajoptpy.kin_utils as ku
from trajoptpy.check_traj import traj_is_safe, traj_collisions
import trajoptpy.math_utils as mu
```

actually the main error is importing trajopt as

```
ImportError: No module named trajoptpy
```

I have downloaded the github package of **trajopt** but after compiling 
I don't know PYTHONPATH is making problem or other dependency 
in my PC I have set the path as

```
mudasser@mudasser-PC:~$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/mudasser/trajopt
mudasser@mudasser-PC:~$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/mudasser/trajopt/build/lib
```

now while **ctest** and running the python code it is making problem for me.
**ctest** error is given as

```
Test project /home/mudasser/trajopt/build
  Start  1: arm_to_joint_target.py
1/10 Test  #1: arm_to_joint_target.py .............   Passed    5.10 sec
  Start  2: arm_to_cart_target.py
2/10 Test  #2: arm_to_cart_target.py ..............***Failed    2.46 sec
  Start  3: fullbody_plan.py
3/10 Test  #3: fullbody_plan.py ...................***Failed    2.44 sec
  Start  4: position_base.py
4/10 Test  #4: position_base.py ...................***Failed    0.03 sec
  Start  5: this_side_up.py
5/10 Test  #5: this_side_up.py ....................***Failed    2.25 sec
  Start  6: arm_to_cart_target_position_only
6/10 Test  #6: arm_to_cart_target_position_only ...***Failed    2.99 sec
  Start  7: sco-unit
7/10 Test  #7: sco-unit ...........................   Passed    0.08 sec
  Start  8: collision-checker-unit
8/10 Test  #8: collision-checker-unit .............***Failed    0.00 sec
  Start  9: planning-unit
9/10 Test  #9: planning-unit ......................***Failed    0.00 sec
  Start 10: cast-cost-unit
10/10 Test #10: cast-cost-unit .....................***Failed    0.00 sec

20% tests passed, 8 tests failed out of 10

Total Test time (real) =  15.36 sec

The following tests FAILED:
  2 - arm_to_cart_target.py (Failed)
  3 - fullbody_plan.py (Failed)
  4 - position_base.py (Failed)
  5 - this_side_up.py (Failed)
  6 - arm_to_cart_target_position_only (Failed)
  8 - collision-checker-unit (Failed)
  9 - planning-unit (Failed)
 10 - cast-cost-unit (Failed)
Errors while running CTest
```

can someone help me to fix trajopt problem?

Comment: Your `PYTHONPATH` uses `/home/trajopt` but your test uses `/home/mudasser/trajopt`. Is this a typo?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi sorry for that but i exported again and having same problem 20% complete 'em gona update the question you can see it